# If $\cos (α + β) = 4 / 5$ and $\sin (α – β) = 5 / 13$, where $α$ lie between $0$ and $\pi/4$, find the value of $\tan2α$.

Tags: trigonometry

In my textbook, the given answer is only $\frac{56}{33}$. But I think the question has another answer $(\frac{16}{63})$ as well.

Please review the attached answer, share your thoughts and correct me if I am wrong. Thank You! [image]

Comment: Can you justify the $\pm$ in your second and third lines? ($\pm\frac34$ and $\pm\frac5{12}$)

Comment: cos(α+β) = 4/5 => sec(α+β) = 5/4 => sec^2(α+β) = 25/16 => 1 + tan^2(α+β) = 25/16 => tan^2(α+β) = 9/16 => tan(α+β)= +3/4 or - 3/4

Comment: Ah, but that's like saying that $x = 1 \implies x^2 = 1 \implies x = \pm 1$.

Comment: Same in the 3rd step for tan(α-β)

Comment: Yes you are right!! But, Given cos (α+β) = 4/5 >0 => (α+β) lies in 1st or 4th quadrant. If  (α+β) is in 1st quadrant, then tan (α+β) >0 & If  (α+β) is in 4th quadrant, then tan (α+β) <0. So that's why +/- 3/4

Comment: Solving the two equations gives $2 \alpha = (-1)^k \arcsin(5/13) \pm \arccos(4/5) + \pi k$. Show that there is only one such $\alpha$ in $(0, \pi/4)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\sin(\alpha-\beta)\gt 0$, we must have $0\lt \alpha-\beta\lt \pi \implies \beta\lt \alpha$ and together with $0\lt \alpha \lt \frac{\pi}{4}$, this means that $0\lt \beta \lt \frac{\pi}{4}$. This further implies that $$0\lt \alpha-\beta \lt \frac{\pi}{4}$$ so $$\tan(\alpha-\beta) \gt 0$$ Your textbook is right.

Comment: $\alpha - \beta \in (0, \pi)$ is not necessarily true, we only know that $\alpha - \beta \in (2 k \pi, (2 k + 1) \pi)$.